# Javascript timestamps are invalid

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I have been fiddeling with javascripts timestamps the whole morning now. I keep getting invalid timestamps by running

`today = (new Date()).setHours(0,0,0,0)` or `today = (new Date()).getTime()`

These 2 output `1338930000000` and `1338978151748`.

I figured this was just a chrome js engine error but reproduced it with Firefox. The expected output of those 2 statements were `1338930000` and `1338977700`.

I do, however, have a fix for this. The fix is this:

`today = parseInt(((new Date()).setHours(0,0,0,0) * Math.pow(10, -3)).toFixed(0))`

or without setHours()

`today = parseInt(((new Date()) * Math.pow(10, -3)).toFixed(0))`

Is this a common bug? Am I doing something wrong to get these results? The timestamps are in format timestamp * 10^3.

EDIT:

TURNS OUT I WAS EXPECTING THE TIME IN SECONDS (darn you PHP) WHILE JAVASCRIPT OUTPUTS IT IN MILLISECONDS. I am using the phpJS date / time library, and javasctipt timestamp doesn't seem to be natively compitable with strtotime() and date()

I was trying to work with unix timestamps, those are in seconds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getTime()` returns the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01, not seconds.

```
//milliseconds
var milliseconds = new Date().getTime();

//seconds
var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
```

Comment: Damn ! thought it was seconds ! +1

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug - you are expecting a timestamp in seconds (why?), while javascript gives timestamps with milliseconds precision.

Answer (score 1):

Unix timestamps use seconds but Javascript timestamps use milliseconds! That's why you need to multiply.divide by 1000.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp

> The UTC() method returns the number of milliseconds between a
>   specified date and midnight of January 1, 1970, according to universal
>   time.

Comment: Using phpJS date/time functions screwed me over ;) I mainly develop PHP, so I was used to timestamps being in seconds. Good to know. Thank you!